# How to make a general function for Appollo call?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

There is such a code:

```
    fun getCallFrom(query: Query<*, *, *>): ApolloQueryCall<out Any?> = apolloClient.query(query)

    fun test() {
        val response1: com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<MyTestQuery.Data> = apolloClient.query(
            MyTestQuery("test")
        ).await()
        
        val response2: com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<out Any?> = getCallFrom(
            MyTestQuery("test")
        ).await()
    }
```

You can see in the `test()` function there are two `responses` (`response1 & response2`) the differences in the type of the responses as for the first one I used `appoloClient.query` and for the second one I used my general function.

The problem is that I need to get the same result type from my general function as for the `response1` (`com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<MyTestQuery.Data>`).

I tried to play with different types of passing instead of the `*`, however, nothing worked.

The question is - what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I solved this issue with such an approach:

```
private fun<X: Operation.Data, Y, Z: Operation.Variables> getCallFrom(query: Query<X, Y, Z>): ApolloQueryCall<Y>? = apolloClient.query(query)
```